# Can Serilog output level "Trace" instead of "Verbose"?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5, serilog

I'm using serilog with ASP.Net in .Net 5 and I'm using the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.
The problem is when I put the following in my code:

```
logger.Log(LogLevel.Trace, "Trace message")
```

Serilog outputs a log level of "Verbose".

I know that this is Serilog's equivalent but is there a simple way to get Serilog to output this level as "Trace"? It's slightly confusing the output being different to what I put in my code?

I'm currently writing to Console and PostgreSQL while I develop but it's likely to have different sinks added when we start deploying to Azure Kubernetes Service, e.g. Application Insights.

Answer (score 12):

Serilog doesn't contain Trace log level.
Refer to [Documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics) Serilog supports these levels:

- Verbose
- Debug
- Information
- Warning
- Error
- Fatal

Comment: This may be useful to others: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/issues/57